# How to convert a Date to a formatted string in VB.net?

Tags: .net, vb.net, date, datetime, type-conversion

There seems to be a million questions here on converting a string to a Date, but not vice-versa. When I convert a Date object to a string using `mydate.toString` I get a string in the format `16/01/2013 13:00:00`.

But what I really want is `2013-01-16 13:00:00`. I can't see any functions on the Date object that do this for me, do I need to use a regex or something instead?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can use the ToString overload. Have a look at [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx) for more info

So just Use `myDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")`

or something equivalent

Comment: Thanks! Didn't realise the toString method was overloaded.

Comment: A small but important tip  - use "MM" for months in capital letters. Else you will get minutes instead of months.

Comment: This also works directly with system.datetime.now

Answer (score 11):

you can do it using the format function, here is a sample:

```
Format(mydate, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
```

Answer (score 5):

```
myDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
```

the capital HH is for 24 hours format as you specified

Answer (score 5):

I like:

```
Dim timeFormat As String = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
myDate.ToString(timeFormat)
```

Easy to maintain if you need to use it in several parts of your code, date formats always seem to change sooner or later.

Answer (score 4):

```
Dim timeFormat As String = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
objBL.date = Convert.ToDateTime(txtDate.Value).ToString(timeFormat)
```

Comment: Convert.ToDateTime(txtDate.value).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")