# try to convert date to string in visual basic .net

Tags: vb.net, string, date, datetime, varchar

I want to convert a date value to string in vb.net, but its not working
heres my code in vb.net when try to convert to string

```
While (sqlReader.Read())
....
 pro.fechaOperacion = Convert.ToString(sqlReader.GetString(3))
end while
```

and this is my code for my stored proc

```
select ...
 Convert (date, EN.FECHA,103),
...from Fact
```

Please I need your help.

Comment: What are the errors you're getting? How does it not work? You also don't need to convert a string to a string...

Comment: yourdate.tostring() hmm. make clear your question. date in? string to? etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a Date to a formatted string in VB.net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14359616/how-to-convert-a-date-to-a-formatted-string-in-vb-net)

Comment: You have a date, `fechaOperacion`, you convert it to string so you can convert it do date.  Why?

Comment: thanks man it works!! @AndrewMorton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will run into unnecessary complications if you use strings for dates in your code. The only times you normally need to convert between the two are for input and output.

You can modify your code (as shown) to achieve that:

- make `pro.fechaOperacion` a `DateTime` instead of a `String`.
- select it value with `SELECT ... [date] ... FROM Fact`*.
- retrieve its value with `pro.fechaOperacion = sqlReader.GetDateTime(3)`.

* Use the appropriate delimiters for your database if `[` and `]` are wrong.